Best way to capture verbosity in Redshift error
I frequently run into issues with Redshift where I have multiple columns in the same table with the same varchar length. When i try to run an insert statement where a value is greater than the allotted column length, i get a generic error like ERROR: value too long for type character varying(32). If all my varchar columns are of length 32, what is the best way to capture the column name that is actually failing? This part of an automated procedure where the queries are executed as insert into table1 (select col1, col2, ... from table2)
My current "debugging" method is to generate the dataset that is used in the insert statement and run a max(length()) to figure out the problematic record(s). I find this to be very time consuming and there might be a more efficient approach (short of making all the columns varchar(65538))

Have your application catch the error and log the statement and parameters. If PII is a problem, just log the length of the parameters (if they are text type). Bigger question: why restrict column lengths?

One reason to not massively oversize varchar columns is that while this doesn't take up more space on disk, it does make Redshift allocate larger amounts of memory when working with the data.  This can make things run slower.  Now this isn't a big deal if we are talking about varchar(32) vs varchar(40) but going to 64k can be impactful.  I expect there are other application reasons for this but this is one reason.

yup, Bill's answer is exactly the reason we did not go ahead and max out all our varchar column. We do catch and log the error, but the current system still needs human intervention to update the column name which is something that I can easily grab at the moment otherwise i would automate the entire workflow

You don't mention what you do when you "figure out the problematic record(s)" and this would impact what I'd want to do.  If this keeps happening then the better approach is to not improve the debugging bur rather improve the data processing.
If you just truncate the data when this happens then I'd just insert the first 32 characters.
If you need to trace back the offending record back to the source then I'd say this is a data validation problem and should be detected before insertion into the warehouse.
What action do you take when you find these issues?

oops sorry i forgot to mention. Our current system is able to truncate if the input record is greater than Redshift's max limit (653538 byte). If the input record is not greater than the max, i would like to double the problematic column's current size. So bump 32 -> 64 bytes in this example

So why don't you just - insert into table1 (select substring(col1,1,64), ... from table2)?  There is likely some aspect of the situation I'm not getting.

so here is an example: lets say table1 col1 is currently set at varchar(32). We select a record from table2 that is varchar(60) and attempt to insert into table1 col1. This will throw the value too long for type character varying(32) error. My intention behind this post was to figure out the col1 name so that i can automate running an alter table statement to double col1's varchar size (assuming it is not already/will max out -- this something we can LBYL). We want to maintain the record intact and try to minimize truncation as much as possible

So you want a process that detects size conflicts and modifies the target table to accept the data.  Possibly with some limits as to what is sane and what needs some user intervention.  Yes?  If so you want a control process.

I'd recommend that you think of it this way.  Have a process that tests the source table sizes and produces the DDL changes needed.  [I'd use octet_length() function in this process, not len(), as this will handle multibyte characters.]  IMO the best way to make a control process is external to Redshift.  A Lambda function, your ETL tooling, ... are more flexible and maintainable than trying to do all of this in a stored procedure but it is possible to do it here.

yup totally agreed. We are moving to a python based solution to make this control process more manageable/flexible. One thing i came across is that the error messages returned by Redshift (like this particular scenario) is lacking some major details and will require us to perform additional diagnostic steps to help us clearly identify the issue
